# functional calculus on a set of normal elements is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb C$. Let $A_K$ denote the set of all normal elements $x$ with $\sigma_A(x)\subset K$. If $f$ is a continuous function on $K$, then the functional calculus :$x\in A_K\to f(x)\in A$ is continuous.

To prove it, the author says, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a polynomial $p$of $\lambda$ , $\bar\lambda$ such that $\sup|p(\lambda,\bar\lambda) - f(\lambda)|<\epsilon.$ Also there is a $\delta>0$ such that $||p(x,x^*) - p(y,y^*)||<\epsilon$ if $||x-y||<\delta$. Then show that $||f(x) - f(y)||<3\epsilon$

My question is that how does he say  there is a $\delta>0$ such that $||p(x,x^*) - p(y,y^*)||<\epsilon$ if $||x-y||<\delta$. I can accept this inequality for functions, but now $p(x,x^*)$ is just an element of $A$.

Please help me to understand it.

Comment: So they're starting with a fixed $f$ and finding a fixed $p$ to approximate $f$. I guess this would come down to showing $\|x^{k}(x^{\star})^{m}-y^{k}(y^{\star})^{m}\|$ can be made small by choosing $\|x-y\|$ small enough. Have you looked at this last expression for normal $x$, $y$ and tried to bound it uniformly assuming both have spectrum in $K$?

Comment: @T.A.E. : Thanks, you are right.

Comment: You're welcome.